# How to search one column in searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to just search one column. (to adapt upon in the future to search dates and location and event type)

I'm using searchkick, Which works lovely however i can search the location when all i want is the event name passed back, However i'm wanting to use the location and others later on. Any help would be great!

Any ideas?
Sam

Answer (score 0):

So i worked this out myself!

You need this code in your controller

```
 fields:["column name here!"]
```

Simples